# How to query post ids liked by the Author

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, post-meta

I'm using wti_like plugin and this is how i get the number(count) of post liked by the author

```
// Get the author object
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );

// Get the post ids liked by the author
$like_ids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post
            WHERE user_id = {$author->ID} AND value > 0
            GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC");
?>

echo (int)$like_count;
```

---

How can i query the posts liked by the author and use my post format to display them in my author.php template?

ie:

```
get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="site-content"> 

        <div id="content" role="main"
< ?
$args = array(
  //QUERY OPTIONS GOES HERE//
);

$wp_query->query( $args ); ?>


        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ? >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would be something like:

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post WHERE user_id = {$author->ID}" );
```

Then you can pass that array of post IDs as the `post__in` argument of `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $post_ids
);
```